# How to access the environment PORT on client side in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm looking to access the Heroku port on the client side.

My app is a monorepo that deploys a node.js server, which serves React code for the client side.

The node.js server can access `process.env.PORT` just fine, however, I cannot access it within my react code.

I tried a few workarounds:

1. Write an `.env` file (with the port) during runtime and read from that. Works locally, but not on production (Heroku) since Heroku won't let you use `fs.writeFileSync`
2. Write to an existing empty `.env` file. This seems more plausible, but I can't get it to work

I tried looking at the solution from here: [How to access $PORT environment variable in React App on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080833/how-to-access-port-environment-variable-in-react-app-on-heroku) but my setup is different. I don't know what `configure(...)` is. All I want is to access `process.env.PORT` on the client side.

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: You don't. Why do you think you need it? Heroku routes incoming traffic on the standard web ports 443 and 80 to your app. You don't need to (and in fact shouldn't) try to use the randomly assigned internal port in your client.

Comment: @Chris I need it for my monorepo. My node js server serves the client side react code, but the client side don't know what port to connect to, since I have to get it from the port environment variable

Comment: The client side should connect to port 80 or 443, not the port given by the `PORT` environment variable. The `PORT` is not exposed directly and cannot accept requests. Only ports 80 and 443 can receive traffic from the Internet. (Note that both 80 and 443 redirect to whatever you are running on `PORT`. You cannot listen on multiple ports, so if you're trying to host back-end and front-end code you'll have to build your front-end and serve it as static files from your back-end or something. I recommend splitting the repo.)

Answer (score 0):

**on your client-side file**

change all `http://localhost:port/` to

`https://yourAppName-app.herokuapp.com/`

It will run properly when you deploy on Heroku.
change it back if you want to work locally.